# How do I obtain a JavaScript object that is created on another php file made by the first page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, object

My problem is I need to access a JavaScript object which is created on another page(php file) and using it in my current page.

So, this is my first page test_ong.php containing 2 buttons. One is to create another page that produced that JavaScript object and another button to retrieve the JavaScript object.

```
<button id="new">Open New Win</button>
<button id="dis">Display</button>
<div id="test"></div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var myChild;
$("#new").click(function() {
    myChild = window.open("test_reg.php","","width=500, height=500, resizable=yes");
});

$("#dis").click(function() {
    console.log('I clicked this');
    $.post("test_reg.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

And my second page test_reg.php which will create the object `whatIWant`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var whatIWant = {
        fruit: "apple",
        car: "Lotus",
        age: 31,
        hobby: "coding"
    };
</script>
```

So, what I want is whenever I click on button Display. It will give me the object `whatIWant` in the console log.

I know I can get this by using `myChild.whatIWant` but I need to refresh my first page and still get the object `myChild.whatIWant`.

Thank you for those who read or answer my question.

Comment: `I need to refresh my first page and still get the object`. If that's your design, maybe you should rethink this design first. If you need refreshing anyway then why don't you make test_ong.php provide the Javascript object to itself instead of calling a second file simultaneously?

Comment: @MarcCompte. I'm actually working on telephony. So, I actually need to include this Sip.js for telephony. The thing is I have a webpage with a number of tab and applets. So, when I maneuver around, my page will reload and thus, disconnecting and connecting my sip.js again. I need this to be a stable connection. Therefore, I thought of putting this sip.js in another page for stable connection while the first page could maneuver and use the JavaScript object for calling and receiving calls continuously.

Comment: It seems there is more here than the code in your question shows. Having tabs shouldn't necessarily mean the page needs reloading every time you do something in it. Maybe the parent document should contain the sip.js and opening whatever file in a tab would not disconnect you. Another approach may be working with session variables, storing the JS object there and retrieving it whenever you need it.

Comment: @MarcCompte. The parent document containing sip.js will not work because the website is designed by others and I'm just pulling it. But I think session variables might work for this case of mine. Thank you so much for your answer and how can I upvote or tick your comment? =)

Comment: You may not have the option to upvote comments yet. I'll put it as an answer and if it works for you then you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your second page should return only the object like:

```
 {
        fruit: "apple",
        car: "Lotus",
        age: 31,
        hobby: "coding"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by ajax call, **you need to first initialize a variable, then through ajax call you can over write it** and then display again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script>var whatIWant = {};</script>
      </head>

 <body>
    <button id="new">Open New Win</button>
    <button id="dis">Display</button>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var myChild;
    $("#new").click(function() {
        myChild = window.open("test_reg.php","","width=500, height=500, resizable=yes");
    });

    $("#dis").click(function() {
        console.log('I clicked this');

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test_reg.php",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {

                    //do something else

                }
            });
    });
    </script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

**Here is your test_Reg.php file :**

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      whatIWant = {fruit: "apple",
      car: "Lotus",
      age: 31,
      hobby: "coding"};
      </script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try storing the JSON as a session variable or in a cookie, and then retrieve it with Javascript. Both should be accessible after page reload.